# Magento 2: How to translate payment module

Tags: magento2

I want to translate this text in payment module:
[image]

in file `magento2-payment/i18n/pl_PL.csv` I found that this text is translated. Just why does not it appear on the frontend?

https://github.com/dotpay/magento2-payment/blob/master/i18n/pl_PL.csv

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are in `pl_PL` store view
2. Make sure you have exactly the right word in `pl_PL.csv`
3. Check in your payment module if you have well the translate **function** like this :

   `<?php echo __('The word to translate'); ?>`
4. if all this doesn't solve the problem, you can translate it in database(Translate inline), you can enable it in : `Stores>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Translate Inline>Enable for Storefront>Yes`. More info [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1222)